# Error converting a xls file to xlsx with PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I´m making a web application in PHP with the library [PHPExcel](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/), one functionality is convert a xls file to xlsx. This is the code for the functionality:

```
<?php
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . '../PHPExcel/Classes/');
include 'PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
$excelPath="/Documents/Excel/";
$inputFileName=$_FILES['file']['name'];
$fileType=$_FILES['file']['type'];
$fileSize=$_FILES['file']['size'];
$fileTemp=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$extension = substr(strrchr($inputFileName, '.'), 1);
if ($extension=="xls"){
    $fileName= "list_file_to_convert.xls";
    $save_as= $excelPath.$fileName;
    move_uploaded_file($fileTemp, $save_as);
    $inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($save_as);
    $excel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($save_as);
    $writer = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($excel, 'Excel2007');
    $writer->save($excelPath."test123.xlsx");
}else{
    echo "everything is ok, a file xlsx has been loaded"; 
}    
?>
```

The problem is, that when i try to use the function:

> PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($save_as);

I get the followings errors:

[image: Error from PHPExcel]

The strange thing is that if I load a file with xlsx format or a CVS file, and is converted to xls or CVS everything is ok, however the error is generated only when the file is loaded with xls extension. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just because a file has an extension of `.xls` doesn't mean anything. What does `$inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($save_as);` tell you the file is? If you open the file in a text editor, what does it look like?

Comment: From the error messages above, it looks like a partial xls file, one without style information.... try loading with `setReadDataOnly(true)`